# iptables port forward rule to route traffic from WireGuard TUN interface to eth0

Tags: iptables, portforwarding, tap, tun

I am using WireGuard (WG) as a VPN and only routing certain port based traffic over it.  On the ingress side of the tunnel the traffic first hits eth0 then goes on to the WG TUN interface, wg0, so the following rule works for forwarding on ingress:

```
-A PREROUTING -d 192.#.#.# -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7054 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.#.#.#:7054
```

However I can not get traffic routed from TUN interface to eth0 on the egress side of the tunnel with the following rule, I think due to the "tunnel" being virtual and the traffic first must cross eth0 so PREROUTING is not valid???  I am not sure how to think about the TUN interface with regards to the routing sequence, i.e. is this still PREROUTEING or POSTROUTING or somewhere in the middle?

```
-A PREROUTING -d 10.#.#.# -i wg0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7054 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.#.#.#:7054
```

I tried the following to see if PREROUTING would then work for the wg0 interface but it did not.  I also tried this with POSTROUTING, but not the solution.

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j NOTRACK
```